# PHP Datetime `next week wednesday` gives me monday

Tags: php, date, datetime

I'm trying to get the next week's Wednesday date using `new \DateTime('next week wednesday')`. However, it returns `2016-12-19 00:00:00.000000` which is Monday. Why is it so? How to get correct result?

I tried to reproduce it in a PHP sandbox online but there it returns correct result http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/7ab99fcfeffedc1ad01d7de9ed236ac273fe1bb3 Can it be something depending on my environment?

I'm running PHP 7 on OSX

> PHP 7.0.11 (cli) (built: Oct  2 2016 00:32:59) ( NTS ) Copyright (c)
>   1997-2016 The PHP Group Zend Engine v3.0.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2016
>   Zend Technologies
>       with Xdebug v2.4.0, Copyright (c) 2002-2016, by Derick Rethans

[image]

Comment: Maybe your system time is 2 days behind?

Comment: @someone The server clock being wrong wouldn't explain getting the wrong date for Wednesday...

Comment: But why would it return Monday if it was behind? I would expect a Wednesday at least. `new \DateTime();` returns `2016-12-18 23:15:43.000000` = now. I think it's set properly.

Comment: Can you give more details of your system? (PHP version, OS, locale etc, maybe phpinfo(), with sensitive info removed)

Comment: Try to reproduce with another version of php

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This [appears to be a bug](https://3v4l.org/MHqP6) (possibly [this one](https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=72719) that only occurs on Sundays):

```
<?php

var_dump(new \DateTime('Wednesday next week'));
```

PHP versions 5.6.23 to 5.6.29 and 7.0.8 to 7.1.0 output December 19 (a Monday), while PHP versions 5.0 to 5.6.22 and 7.0.0 to 7.0.7 return December 28 (a Wednesday).

I don't see any mention of related changes in the changelog entries for PHP 5.6.23 or 7.0.8.

Comment: Ah, looks like an answer, thanks. But I wonder how to deal with this... IMO it's pretty serious :D

Comment: @simPod you are expecting software to interpret natural-language. a little more code and you could do away with "Wednesday next week"

Comment: with `strtotime` I used `strtotime('next wednesday', strtotime('next monday'))` or something like that

Comment: @the_nuts, unfortunately it looks like the bug still exists in PHP 7.1.0, which is currently the newest version (I just fixed a typo in my answer that might have made that unclear).

Comment: @the_nuts yup, I just upgraded to latest 7.0.14 and it's still there

Comment: @Dragon I wanted to avoid it but whatever, there's no other way... It's a bit more complicated in my case but it's not related to this thread.

Comment: *"don't work on Sundays"* - @simPod I never work on Sundays ;-) and if so, it's triple time and a 1/2.

Comment: Up-voting for stating the bug.

Answer (score 0):

I get the same results here, indeed seems to be an 'next week' thingy:

```
$date = new \DateTime('next week wednesday');
print_r($date);

DateTime Object
(
    [date] => 2016-12-19 00:00:00.000000
    [timezone_type] => 3
    [timezone] => Europe/Berlin
)
```

Rewriting seems to work, depending on what you want:

```
$date = new \DateTime('wednesday');
print_r($date);

DateTime Object
(
    [date] => 2016-12-21 00:00:00.000000
    [timezone_type] => 3
    [timezone] => Europe/Berlin
)
```

or

```
$date = new \DateTime('wednesday');
$date->add(new \DateInterval('P1W'));
print_r($date);

DateTime Object
(
    [date] => 2016-12-28 00:00:00.000000
    [timezone_type] => 3
    [timezone] => Europe/Berlin
)
```

Comment: will try this with dateinterval but next sunday :D thanks