# PHP strtotime wrong only on sundays

Tags: php, date, strtotime

Currently I am using the following to get the date of monday and friday of this and next week.

```
$curWeekStart = date('d.m', strtotime('monday this week'));
$curWeekEnd = date('d.m', strtotime('friday this week'));

$nextWeekStart = date('d.m', strtotime('monday next week'));
$nextWeekEnd = date('d.m', strtotime('friday next week'));
```

All works fine until the day "sunday" comes, like today.. then this things above only show me monday and not other days. Tuesday, Wednesday, Thursday, Friday ecc are not working, it is only returning me monday. This error happens only on sundays and not on other days.

That's the output:

```
$curWeekStart == 13.03;
$curWeekEnd == 13.03;

$nextWeekStart == 20.03;
$nextWeekEnd == 20.03;
```

Does anyone have an idea how to solve this? Or do you know an alternative to this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is likely the result of [a bug](https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=72719) that [affected PHP versions 5.6.23 to 5.6.30, 7.0.8 to 7.0.16, and 7.1.0 to 7.1.2](https://3v4l.org/U5FU3). It also [affects the `DateTime` class](https://stackoverflow.com/q/41213380/354577).

The bug was resolved in PHP 7.0.17 and 7.1.3, but is still present in the latest release of PHP 5.6 (5.6.30 at the time of writing), which [now receives only security fixes](http://php.net/supported-versions.php) and therefore probably won't ever receive a fix.

Upgrading PHP to an unaffected version is probably the best solution, but if you need a workaround for an affected version [you should be able to add a `DateInterval` to a `Datetime`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41213830/354577) and get the result you want.

Comment: Thanks. I didn't know there was a bug like this. I think I'll upgrade PHP to a version without that bug.